# How to fit (find $u$) in the binomial options pricing model?

Tags: options, binomial-tree

In the binomial tree options pricing literature, I see frequent reference to the definition that

$$
u = e^{\sigma \sqrt{n/t}}
$$

I think I understand the model, but how do we derive this, i.e. how do I fit the model to data? I've tried to derive it myself but get a different answer, namely

$$
u = \exp(\sigma / 2\sqrt{np(1-p)})
$$

where $p$ is the risk neutral probability. The paper "A Synthesis of Binomial Option Pricing Models for Lognormally Distributed Assets" even argues that the CRR derivations admit arbitrage for discrete time periods.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59716/risk-neutral-probability-for-stock-with-continuous-dividend/59746#59746

Comment: Yes, upvoted, thanks!