Pricing option with k-branch binomial tree, risk neutral pricing
Suppose I have a binomial tree with 4 branches, \$14,\$19, \$24, \$28. I have a call option with strike K=20. How would I compute the price of the call option while respecting risk neutral probabilites? Or is that even relevant here?
There exist nice closed form solutions in the 2-branch case, where I follow the hedging argument. But in the 4 branch case, the u/d moves are asymmetric and moreover, there are two of each. How would I price this?

I would argue that if the current price of the underlying is between 19 and 24, it must first cross 19 or 24, before reaching 28 and 14. So unless we assume some very "weird" dynamics (i.e. an asset that "jumps" to one of the 4 prices, without first crossing the prices closer to its current price), a Binomial tree would seem a more natural / better model.

It's an exotic asian power option, so there are very weird dynamics. So you have one opportunity to hedge before observing the underlying. Then you settle at one of those 4 prices (with no opportunity to hedge in between).

I understand that you are pondering a $k$-nomial tree, thereby introducing additional degrees of freedom for modelling. Have a look at this answer https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59716/risk-neutral-probability-for-stock-with-continuous-dividend/59746#59746 - maybe it gives you a starting point for further discussion.
What additional assumptions are you willing to add to your model regarding the shape of the return/price distribution?
